# Could not able to run mvn commands from jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins

## when i try to run mvn commands from jenkins getting below error

Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Have you try to run mvn successfully from the machine when you are logged in as jenkins user?

Comment: You should provide more information about your Jenkins and Maven configuration. Please take a look to [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: able to run mvn commands from terminal on my mac machine, facing issue only when i run mvn commands from jenkins

Answer (score 0):

you can run mvn build step to run the mvn commands , and make sure to add mvn installation in the the config settings.

if you must run the mvn command in bash step , make sure that mvn exist on your machine (if not you can run a dummy command ( clean or version )as a mvn step and use this installation)

PLS check the **path** command in the bash step , i think there is a different between connect as Jenkins or manually. if  this is the problem you can use the **source ~/.bashrc**

Comment: Able to run mvn commands in local machine, facing issue only while running mvn commands from jenkins